# MPAndroidChart with null values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and am really enjoying it.

A 'little' need I have is that I can put null values to the 'entrys'. I'm monitoring the apache conections on servers of my system, and I would to see if they is down (where I put the null value) or if they just no conections (0).

I tried, but the Entry class don't accept 'null' as value showing the message: 'The constructor Entry(null, int) is undefined'

Thanks!

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/40448081

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution for you could be to **check weather the object you received is null**, or not. If the object is null, you don't even create an `Entry` object instead of just setting it's value to null.

Example:

```
// array that contains the information you want to display
ConnectionHolder[] connectionHolders = ...;

ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
int cnt = 0;

for(ConnectionHolder ch : connectionHolders) {

    if(ch != null) entries.add(new Entry(ch.getNrOfConnections(), cnt));
    else {
        // do nothing
    }

    cnt++; // always increment
}
```

This would create e.g. a `LineChart` where no circles are drawn on indices where the `ConnectionHolder` object was null.

For a future release of the library, I will try to add the feature so that null values are supported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't work... he just make a 'big line' between the two points... I need that this null point show a empty space.

So, while you support this I'll try make a circle with a different color.. it's possible, alright?
Would you like that I post as issue in github?

Comment: Exactly, It's not working. I'm sending the right xIndex and corresponding value, and it's drawing a line between the xIndex's

Comment: I am still not able to find a solution for this, its doesn't support null values also if i ignore those items from entry it ignore them from labels as well.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to draw another DataSet with TRANSPARENT (or arbitrary) color:
 - chart with fixed number of X values
 - Y values are updated periodically
 - boolean flag indicate transparent part (or another color)

```
private static final int SERIES_SIZE = 360; 
int xIndex = -1;
float xIndexVal;
private LineChart chart;
private boolean currentFlag;

public void createChart(LineDataSet dataSet) {
    LineData chartData = new LineData();
    prepareDataSet(dataSet);
    chartData.addDataSet(dataSet);
    for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_SIZE; i++) {
        chartData.addXValue("" /*+ i*/);
    }
    chart.setData(chartData);

}

private void prepareDataSet(LineDataSet dataSet, YAxis axis, int color) {
    // configure set 
}


public void update(Float val, boolean flag) {
    List<ILineDataSet> dsl = chart.getData().getDataSets();
    Log.d("chart", String.format("%s --- %d sets, index %d", descr,  dsl.size(), xIndex));

    if (xIndex == SERIES_SIZE - 1) {

        // remove all entries at X index 0
        for (int i = 0; i < chart.getData().getDataSetCount(); i++) {
            Entry entry0 = chart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(i).getEntryForIndex(0);
            if (entry0 != null && entry0.getXIndex() == 0) {
                chart.getData().removeEntry(entry0, i);
                Log.d("chart", String.format("entry 0 removed from dataset %d, %d entries in the set", i, chart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(i).getEntryCount()));
            }
            else {
                Log.d("chart", String.format("all %d entries in the set kept", chart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(i).getEntryCount()));
            }
        }

        // remove empty set, if any
        for (Iterator<ILineDataSet> mit = dsl.iterator(); mit.hasNext(); ) {
            if (mit.next().getEntryCount() == 0) {
                mit.remove();
                Log.d("chart", String.format("set removed, %d sets", dsl.size()));
            }
        }

        // move all entries by -1
        for (ILineDataSet ds : dsl) {
            for (Entry entry : ((LineDataSet)ds).getYVals()) {
                entry.setXIndex(entry.getXIndex() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        xIndex++;
    }

    if (currentFlag != flag) {
        currentFlag = !currentFlag;
        LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "");
        prepareDataSet(set, chart.getAxisLeft(), currentFlag ?  Color.TRANSPARENT : Color.BLUE);
        chart.getData().addDataSet(set);

        if (xIndex != 0) {
            chart.getData().addEntry(new Entry(xIndexVal, xIndex - 1), dsl.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    xIndexVal = val;

    chart.getData().addEntry(new Entry(val, xIndex), dsl.size() - 1);

    chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chart.invalidate();
}
```