# MPAndroidChart Linechart unconnected data points

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am investigating `MPAndroidChart` for usage in my company's Android and iOS application and I have found a problem that I need a solution to in order to be able to use this framework.

The application will mostly use the Line Chart functionality and the supplied data can contain `NULL` entries. I have seen other posts that discusses this matter and apparently there is no solution to showing `NULL` values yet. [MPAndroidChart with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328151/mpandroidchart-with-null-values)

The author suggests simply not adding the data point to the set, but in my case it's very important that there is a "hole" in the graph were there is more than two consecutive `NULL` values (or however to represent it) i.e that the graph is not continous between two points with `NULL` values in between. Is there any way I can accomplish this with this framework?

I have been looking into the possibility of separating the data points into different data sets, but it seems like kind of a hack.

Thank you!

Dataset example:

```
[1 2 10 NULL NULL NULL 20 25 30]
The Line must NOT connect the numbers 10 and 20.
```

Comment: you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Nope, that single detail made me switch to AndroidPlot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I ended up coming up with to solve this - for anyone in the future. It iterates through and creates new entries in a data set until it hits a null value, and then it creates data sets with "fake" entries that use a boolean in the entry constructor. Boolean can be found from

> "entry.getData()"

and you can then you can use this to set that Dataset to not be visible

> "mLineDataSet.setVisible(false);"

Note: Do not try to set Dataset Color to transparent - the library has a bug where if certain entries are null the graph doesn't even appear.

```
    private void createDataSets() {
          for (int index = 0; index < mGraph.getGraphDataSets().size(); index++) {
                    lastIndexCreated = 0;
                    final GraphDataSet mDataSet = mGraph.getGraphDataSets().get(index);
                    final ArrayList<Entry> mEntries = getEntries(mDataSet.getYValues(), lastIndexCreated);
                    final LineDataSet mLineDataSet = getDataSet(mEntries, mDataSet, color);
                    mGraphLineData.addDataSet(mLineDataSet);
                    lastIndexCreated = mEntries.size() - 1;
                    while (lastIndexCreated < mDataSet.getYValues().size() - 1) {

                        final LineDataSet set = getDataSet(mEntriesSet, mDataSet, colorSecondary);
                        if (mEntriesSet.size() != 0)
                            mGraphLineData.addDataSet(set);
                        lastIndexCreated = (int) mEntriesSet.get(mEntriesSet.size() - 1).getX();
                    }
                }
    }

    private ArrayList<Entry> getEntries(final List<Float> yValues, final int firstValueIndex) {
            final ArrayList<Entry> mEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = firstValueIndex; i < yValues.size(); i++) {
                if (yValues.get(i) != null)
                 //boolean here is false means that dataset is not fake and should be shown
                    mEntries.add(new Entry(i, yValues.get(i), false));
                else if (firstValueIndex == i) {
                //add a "Fake" data entry, and use mEntry.getData to set line to not be visible.
                    mEntries.add(new Entry(i, 0, true));
                    break;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return mEntries;
        }
```

Comment: Does it work as expected? Does the graphs still feel smooth?

Comment: Yup very smooth