# How to not draw zero values on a linechart while showing their X axis values on MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linegraph

I'm using MPAndroidChart to display my data in a line graph. For each date I have its own value.

This works just fine. What I want to do now is to not draw the 0 values, but instead draw the line between 2 adjacent non-zero values (like a trend-line), while keep showing the dates on the x-axis for the zero values.

My current graph:
[image: My current graph]

The desired graph should look similar to this graph:
[image: Desired graph - no zero values]

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm posting my friend's solution here (worked like a charm):

1. Create a **dataset with 0 values**. Draw it but with line of **transparent color**.
2. Create a **dataset without 0**. Draw it **with the color** that you need.

Put (1) and (2) on the same LineChart.

It will give you an **x axis** with x values where there are **0 values** but will not draw a line for them.

The second dataset will show the **line of data** points **without the 0 values**.

Comment: Great! Can you please post it as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328151/mpandroidchart-with-null-values) as well?

Answer (score 3):

Without drawing two lines like limlim suggested, you have to add only non zero values to your entries, but the x value has to be incremented anyway:

```
List<SomeClass> values = new ArrayList<>();

int k = 0;
List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
for (SomeClass v : values){
  if (v.value > 0){
    entries.add(new Entry(k, v.value));
  }
  k += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to split dataset to draw empty points for MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0.
All you have to do is set those empty points value as Float.NaN (in case of Kotlin).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33908242)